# jquery defer not waiting before calling .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm using defer's .done to wait for a cookie to be loaded before the function finishes. When I try to run the code it finishes and returns undefined. It seems like .done is firing before the first code can finish.

```
function getCookie(cookieName){
    var value;
    var defer = new jQuery.Deferred();
    fetchCookie().done(
        function(){
            return value;
        }
    );
    function fetchCookie(){
        chrome.cookies.get(
            {
            'url':'https://addictedtogether.com/',
            'name':cookieName
            },
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                value=data.value;
            }
        );
        return defer.promise();
    }
}

//usage
var username=getCookie('username');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred objects won't let you avoid callbacks. You still would need to be doing something like this (assuming everything is implemented correctly):

```
getCookie('username').then(function(username){
    console.log(username);
});
```

It will just generate unneeded overhead. I would rather simply do:

```
function getCookie(cookieName, callback){
    chrome.cookies.get(
        {
            'url':'https://addictedtogether.com/',
            'name':cookieName
        },
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
            value=data.value;
            if(callback) {
                callback(value);
            }
        }
    );
}

//usage
getCookie('username', function(username){
    console.log(username);
});
```

Comment: That method works fine but I ideally would like to have the getCookie() function to return the value of the cookie like I described in my code. Is there a clever way to force a function to wait to return a value. I know I could use setInterval() but it seems overly clunky. Thanks!

Comment: @devnill I am not aware of any methods besides using timers.